# Why does the Google Tag Manager automaticalls has a Trigger event for gtm.load for my custom variables?

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

So I want to Trigger my Tags when the user accept cookies, obviously.

I tried different approaches, JSVariable, Custom JS, First party cookie and datalayer variable.
Now I have them all set in Triggers, for example if the JSVariable is true or if the first party cookie contains the cookie value I set, or the datalayer variable contains filled.

Now in Debug mode these Triggers actually seem to work. They all get Ticks under firing triggers, but the Tags don't seem to Trigger because I get another Trigger for some reason which states
gtm.load equals [variableName] (for example: gtm.load equals myJSVariable) and it always has this red X.

I just don't seem to find an answer to this problem.

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone experienceses something similar (in case I am not the only dummy):

When you type in the eventname, it is about WHEN to look for your variable basically.

So for example you would enter gtm.load, when the site has been completely loaded. Then GTM would look for your CustomVariable